# QWebElement manipulation of a QWebPage in a separate thread

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebelement, qwebpage

I have a QWebPage created in the main thread (you can't create it anywhere else). I would like to manipulate this page using the QWebElement API introduced in Qt 4.6, but in a separate thread. So that thread would acquire a reference to the page and perform the necessary tree walking and attribute changes I need.

As the [Threads and QObjects](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/threads-qobject.html) doc page explains, it is unsafe to manipulate QObjects in threads that don't own them *unless* the developer can ensure that the QObject in question will not be processing events while this manipulation is going on.

Now, this QWebPage is also being displayed in a QWebView, but the main thread will be blocked while waiting for the worker thread to finish (actually many of them, working on many different pages). Hence, the main event loop will not be running while the operation is in progress.

Thus, I believe the operation to be safe. **Am I mistaken? Have I missed something?** I'm basically asking for reassurance that this will not blow up in my face...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think you're right, and it is safe. At least, you have me convinced :)